# Difference between $nh/2π$ and $\sqrt{\ell(\ell+1)}h/2π$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, atomic-physics, quantum-spin, orbitals

My textbook mentions that the orbital angular momentum is the second formula and the angular momentum of an electron is given by $nh/2π$ in Bohr model.
Please help me realise the link between these formulas or what should I say if someone asks me about the angular momentum of an electron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the component of angular momentum along *just one axis*, then the two formula actually agree nicely. Angular momentum along some axis **is** just some integer (call it $n$ or $l$), times $h/2\pi$. But this isn't actually equal to the total magnitude of angular momentum, which is given by $\sqrt{l(l+1)} h/2\pi$.

It's worth mentioning that the fact that the Bohr model agrees with the angular momentum along one axis is a bit of an accident.

Comment: Oh thanks. That clears some doubts. But then how does spin angular momentum fit into the picture?

Comment: Spin behaves just the same way, but it can also come in half integer quantities. For a spin $s$ particle, the component of spin angular momentum on some axis can be any number $-s \frac{h}{2\pi}, (-s+1)\frac{h}{2\pi},...,s\frac{h}{2\pi}$. An electron has $s=\frac{1}{2}$, so its angular momentum along any axis can be $\pm\frac{1}{2} \frac{h}{2\pi}$.

Comment: Well then what would I call the total angular momentum of the electron ? Is it the vector sum of the spin and orbital angular momentum? Or something else?

Comment: @NightKruger Adding 2 angular momenta is not like classical addition of vectors, rather it involves expressing the tensor product of two representations of SU(2) [one for each angular momentum] and then expressing that as a sum of representations for the total angular momentum. That's not going to fit in a comment.